# I need to reduce the lines of my code because in my class they demand a total of lines

Tags: java

You who know everything and can there is some way to reduce the lines of this code thank you. is that in my subject they ask us to reduce the codes in their maximum possible and I do not know how to do it with this

```
Cliente cliente=new Cliente(agregar.txt_cedulaCliente.getText(), agregar.txt_nombreCliente.getText(), agregar.txt_tfCliente.getText(), agregar.txt_direccion.getText(), null);

    if (ordenIngreso.equals("primero")) {
        menu.centralCliente.insertarAlComienzo(cliente);
    } else {
        if (menu.centralCliente.getPrimero() != null) {

            if (ordenIngreso.equals("antes")) {

                if (!txtCodigoAnterior.getText().equals(null)) {

                    try {
                        menu.centralCliente.insertarAntesDe(txtCodigoAnterior.getText(), cliente);

                    } catch (NoExisteException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(OrdenCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            } else if (ordenIngreso.equals("despues")) {

                if (!txtCodigoSiguiente.getText().equals("")) {

                    if (menu.centralCliente.buscarCliente(txtCodigoSiguiente.getText()) != null) {

                        try {
                            menu.centralCliente.insertarDespuesDe(txtCodigoSiguiente.getText(), cliente);
                        } catch (NoExisteException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(OrdenCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (ordenIngreso.equals("ultimo")) {
                menu.centralCliente.insertarAlFinal(cliente);
            }

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay clientes en la lista");
        }

    }
```

Comment: What about replace else if to switch-cases?

Comment: I tried it several times but it does not run

Answer (score 1):

when you only have if block, with no else, you should use

```
if (statement && statement)
```

instead of

```
if (statement) {
    if (statement) {
        ....
```

so in your case, use

```
if (!txtCodigoSiguiente.getText().equals("") && menu.centralCliente.buscarCliente(txtCodigoSiguiente.getText()) != null) {
    try {
        menu.centralCliente.insertarDespuesDe(txtCodigoSiguiente.getText(), cliente);
    } catch (NoExisteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OrdenCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```